# Starting Spring Boot as a foreground process from within a bash script

Tags: java, spring, bash, war

I package my Spring Boot war with embedded Tomcat servlet container. And deploy it as a regular java application using `java -jar server.war <Spring Args>`. I wrote a bash script that would take care of deploying the server as a background/foreground process:

```
start_foreground() {
    cmd="$JAVACMD ${JVM_OPTS} -jar ${WAR_FILE} ${SPRING_OPTS}"
    echo "\"${cmd}\""
    eval ${cmd}
    print_log "Server is stopped."
}

start_background() {
    SPRING_OPTS="--spring.pid.file=${PID_FILE} ${SPRING_OPTS}"
    cmd="nohup $JAVACMD ${JVM_OPTS} -jar ${WAR_FILE} ${SPRING_OPTS} &>${LOG_PATH}/console.log &"
    echo "\"${cmd}\""
    eval ${cmd}
    PID=$!
    print_log "Server is started with pid \"${PID}\""
}
```

As you can see, for background process start I use `nohup`. Everything is working fine, it sends `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to my `${LOG_PATH}/console.log`. `console.log` reports that my server is up and running on preconfigured port (using Spring profiles). I have a profile `dev-https` that configured with port `8443`:

```
spring:
  profiles.active: dev-https
...
---

spring:
    profiles: dev-https
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
    key-store: <path>
    key-store-password: <password>
```

However, when I try to start the server as a foreground process, I get unexpected behavior. Whenever I deploy the server using `start_foreground()`, it starts fine, but the port resets to default `8080`.

If I attach a debugger, and try to get values using `environment.getProperty("server.port")`, it will return empty string (however, if a property is not defined, it usually returns `null`). Moreover, all other properties return expected values:

`environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")=dev-https`

`environment.getProperty("server.ssl.enabled")=true`

etc.

I tried to replace `eval` with `exec` and even run `${cmd}` by itself inside `start_foreground()` bash function, but the port always resets to `8080`, and `server.port` returns empty string.

The weirdest part is that if I execute `${cmd}` in my console (not from within the script), everything works flawlessly (right profile, and right port get used).

Has anyone encountered such weird problem?

Comment: Probably the port is occupied or something? Run `ps aux| grep jar`, `netstat -plant` and see if something is wrong with port or the launch

Comment: @TarunLalwani Nope, the deploy fails if port is occupied. There is something bash related that affects the deployment configuration.

Comment: Can you remove the other function and then try? Also see what process gets launched?

Comment: have you tried to echo using `set -x` + capturing output what is happening with commands

Comment: (and why is your spring boot app named a .war when it is clearly a .jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this problem with a new instance of Spring Boot. Wrote a quick bash script, and everything went fine!

Then, I started playing around with my original script, and found out that I was using `SERVER_PORT` variable (because I had an optional argument `--port <num>` for the user).

Apparently, this environment variable is also used by Spring Framework: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-change-default-server-port#server_port

My mistake was exporting `SERVER_PORT` var (however, I needed it for other reasons).

Solution would be to either remove `export` from `export SERVER_PORT=""` or rename variable to something else (which I ended up doing).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the configuration(like port number etc... only for background and not used for foreground. You have not declared the variable (you missed this line)

```
`SPRING_OPTS="--spring.pid.file=${PID_FILE} ${SPRING_OPTS}"`
```

for foreground.